# preg_split para separar palavras, porém ignorando algumas

Tags: php, regex

Preciso de uma expressão regular que divida uma string, mais especificamente um nome completo de uma pessoa, e transforme num array de palavras.

```
$string = "Wallace de Souza Vizerra";

$array = preg_split('/\s+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

['Wallace', 'de', 'Souza', 'Vizerra']
```

Porém, quando houver as ocorrências `de`, `da`, `do`, `das` e `dos`, elas não devem separadas da palavra seguinte:

```
['Wallace', 'de Souza', 'Vizerra']
```

Alguém que manja de expressão regular poderia me ajudar e me explicar como funcionaria a expressão regular utilizada na resposta?

Se houver alguma forma, também gostaria de remover, através da expressão regular, a primeira palavra também.

Ou seja:

```
$string = "Wallace de Souza Vizerra"
```

Deverá retornar:

```
['de Souza', 'Vizerra']
```

Comment: Eu consegui o primeiro resultado! Com a expressão regular `/(?<!de|da|do|dos|das)\W+/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sucesso, porém não há como remover o primeiro item do `array` resultante do `preg_split` usando a própria função e nem mesmo outra função *`inline`*, por isso, `array_shift` foi usado (poderia também usar `unset($array[0])`).

**`separa_palavras.php`**

```
<?php

$nome_completo = 'Wallace de Souza Vizerra dos Santos';

$resultado = preg_split('/(?<!de|da|do|dos|das)[\s]/i', $nome_completo);
$nome_removido = array_shift($resultado);
reset($resultado); // re-ordena chaves

var_export($resultado);
```

**Saída**

```
array (
  0 => 'de Souza',
  1 => 'Vizerra',
  2 => 'dos Santos',
)
```

Comment: Amigo, o `array_shift` já reordena o `array`. Não precisa do `reset`

Comment: Não foi o que aconteceu ou eu não reparei hahaha mas obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Com [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) você pode usar como critério a regex que você já tem (espaços, desde que não tenha "de", "do", "da", etc antes) e acrescentar a primeira palavra como outra possibilidade:

```
$string = "Wallace de Souza Vizerra";
var_dump(preg_split('/(^\w+\s)|(?<!de|da|do|dos|das)\s/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Eu uso [alternância](https://regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa "ou") para indicar que o *split* deve ser feito considerando duas possibilidades:

- `(^\w+\s)`: a primeira palavra, ou seja, o início da string (`^`), seguido de uma ou mais letras, números ou `_` (`\w+`), seguido de um espaço (`\s`), **ou**
- `(?<!de|da|do|dos|das)\s`: um espaço, desde que antes não tenha "de", "do", "da", "dos" ou "das" - o `(?<!` indica um [*lookbehind* negativo](https://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), que verifica se algo **não** existe antes da posição atual

Assim, o `split` é feito nos espaços ou na primeira palavra. A saída é:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "de Souza"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Vizerra"
}
```

Tive que usar a *flag* `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`, caso contrário a primeira posição do array teria uma string vazia.

---

#### Alternativa: *match* em vez de *split*

Mas também é possível obter o array da forma que você quer usando [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Pois no fundo, [*split* e *match* são dois lados da mesma moeda](http://rexegg.com/regex-style.html#splitvsmatch):

- no *split* eu digo o que eu **não** quero que faça parte do resultado final (espaços, desde que antes deles não tenha "de", "do", "da", etc, ou a primeira palavra)
- no *match* eu digo o que eu quero (palavras, exceto a primeira, mas se antes tiver "de", "do", etc, então eu junto com a palavra seguinte).

Sendo assim, a regex ficaria:

```
$string = "Wallace de Souza Vizerra";
if (preg_match_all('/(?:^\w+\s\K)?(?:d(?:e|[ao]s?)\s)?\w+/', $string, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[0]);
}
```

Todos os parênteses estão com `(?:` para formar [grupos de não-captura](http://regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap). Se usar somente parênteses sem o `?:`, eles se tornam grupos de captura e cada grupo é retornado separadamente no array `$matches`, mas como os grupos não me interessam (somente o *match* todo), então eu uso grupos de não-captura para que o array não tenha mais coisas do que eu preciso.

O trecho `d(?:e|[ao]s?)\s` é uma outra forma de dizer que pode ter "de", "do", "da", "dos" ou "das". Eu uso [alternância](https://regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) para dizer que depois da letra `d`, pode ter duas possibilidades:

- a letra `e`
- uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (`[ao]`) para indicar que posso ter a letra `a` ou a letra `o`, e depois delas tem um `s` [opcional](https://regular-expressions.info/optional.html) (`s?`).

<sup>*Eu não usei isso no exemplo com `preg_split` porque dentro de um lookbehind a regex não aceita padrões com tamanho variável (por causa do `?`), então aquela expressão só funciona usando padrões com tamanho fixo.*</sup>

Tudo isso seguido de um espaço ( `\s` - detalhe que este atalho também pega quebras de linha e outros caracteres, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052) para mais detalhes). Ou seja, este trecho pega "de", "do", "da", "dos" ou "das", seguido de um espaço. E o `?` logo depois torna todo este trecho opcional (pois nem todas as palavras terão isso antes).

Depois temos `\w+`, que pega uma ou mais ocorrências de letras, números ou o caractere `_`.

E no início temos o grande truque para ignorar a primeira palavra: primeiro o trecho `^\w+\s` pega o início da string (o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`), seguido de `\w+` (uma ou mais letras, números ou `_`) seguido de um espaço (`\s`). Depois temos o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) `\K`, que segundo a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) serve para descartar o trecho que foi encontrado até então.

Ou seja, a regex encontra a primeira palavra seguida de espaço (`^\w+\s`), mas depois encontra o `\K`, o que faz com que essa palavra seja descartada do *match*, e por isso ela não fará parte do resultado final.

Isso faz com que a primeira palavra seja pega, e em seguida descartada. Depois o restante da regex pega da segunda palavra em diante. O detalhe é que só a segunda palavra terá o trecho `^\w+\s\K` antes dela, por isso eu deixo este trecho opcional (colocando o `?` logo depois). Assim, ao encontrar a segunda palavra, o `\K` descarta o que veio antes (no caso, a primeira palavra), e da terceira palavra em diante, ele não descarta nada.

A saída do código acima é:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "de Souza"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Vizerra"
}
```

Eu pego somente `$matches[0]` porque `preg_match_all` cria um array de arrays. Mas neste caso, esta regex vai gerar um array com somente uma posição, contendo outro array com os resultados que você precisa. Então basta pegar `$matches[0]`.

---

Outro teste:

```
$string = 'Fulano da Silva dos Santos das Dores Teixeira de Carvalho etc blablabla do fim do mundo';
if (preg_match_all('/(?:^\w+\s\K)?(?:d(?:e|[ao]s?)\s)?\w+/u', $string, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[0]);
}
```

Saída:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "da Silva"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "dos Santos"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "das Dores"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "Teixeira"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "de Carvalho"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "etc"
  [6]=>
  string(9) "blablabla"
  [7]=>
  string(6) "do fim"
  [8]=>
  string(8) "do mundo"
}
```

---

Como já dito, `\w` pega letras, números e o caractere `_` (ou seja, `1_23` também é considerado uma "palavra"). Se quiser ser mais específico, pode usar `[a-zA-Z]` para pegar somente letras, mas isso não vai pegar letras acentuadas. Então uma alternativa é usar [*Unicode character properties*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php):

```
$string = "Fábio de Souza Lázaro do Patrocínio";
if (preg_match_all('/(?:^\p{L}+\s\K)?(?:d(?:e|[ao]s?)\s)?\p{L}+/u', $string, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[0]);
}
```

`\p{L}` pega qualquer letra definida pelo Unicode (incluindo letras de outros alfabetos, como o japonês, árabe, etc). Não esqueça de usar a [*flag* `u`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (logo depois da segunda barra que delimita a regex), senão o `\p{L}` não funciona.

A saída é:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "de Souza"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Lázaro"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "do Patrocínio"
}
```

---

#### *match* vs *split*

Se bem que nesse caso, o *split* me parece mais "fácil" (ou menos complicado) que o *match*. De qualquer forma, é interessante saber que você pode obter os mesmos resultados usando ambas as abordagens. Se o critério para um estiver muito difícil, às vezes é mais fácil usar o outro.

Outro detalhe é que as soluções acima só consideram o caso em que há apenas um espaço entre as palavras. Mas se a string for por exemplo `"Wallace    de   Souza   Vizerra"`, bastaria alterar a regex para considerar um ou mais espaços (`\s+`):

```
$string = "Wallace    de   Souza   Vizerra";
if (preg_match_all('/(?:^\w+\s+\K)?(?:d(?:e|[ao]s?)\s+)?\w+/', $string, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Saída:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "de   Souza"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Vizerra"
  }
}
```

Porém, com `preg_split` não funciona se usar `\s+`:

```
$string = "Wallace    de   Souza   Vizerra";
var_dump(preg_split('/(^\w+\s+)|(?<!de|da|do|dos|das)\s+/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

Saída:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "de "
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Souza"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "Vizerra"
}
```

Fiquei tentando encontrar uma solução para o *split*, mas até o momento sem sucesso. Ou seja, esse é um caso em que o *match* acabou sendo mais "fácil" que o *split*.